# Different and wrong output every time the code runs while solving a problem using maps in golang

Tags: go

I was doing [Day 07](https://adventofcode.com/2020/day/7) of last year's Advent of Code and solved it in Python ([like this](https://github.com/luciferchase/advent-of-code/blob/main/2020/python/day-07.py)).
I am trying to learn Go and tried a similar approach in Go as well. I am storing all the relations in a `map` like this:

```golang
map[baseColour1:[Colours{subColour1, noOfBags}, Colours{subColour2, noOfBags}...], baseColour2:...
```

Here is the complete code so far:

```golang
package main
import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "regexp"
    "strings"
    "strconv"
)

// Part 1
// Find relation between all the colours
type Colours struct {
    subColour   string
    noOfBag     int
}

// To reuse for Part 2
func relationBetweenColours(input [][]string) (relation map[string][]Colours) {
    relation = make(map[string][]Colours)

    for _, rule := range input {
        baseColour := strings.Join(rule[:2], " ")
        relation[baseColour] = make([]Colours, 0)

        for i := range rule {
            match, _ := regexp.MatchString("\\d", rule[i])
            if match {
                subColour := strings.Join(rule[i + 1:i + 3], " ")
                noOfBag, _ := strconv.Atoi(rule[i])
                relation[baseColour] = append(relation[baseColour], Colours{subColour, noOfBag})
            }
        }
    }
    return
}

func checkMembership(input []string, element string) (bool) {
    for _, value := range input {
        if (value == element) { return true }
    }
    return false
}

func part1(relation map[string][]Colours) (count int) {
    // Strip relation of extra information
    relevantRelation := make(map[string][]string)

    for baseColour, arrayOfColours := range relation {
        relevantRelation[baseColour] = make([]string, 0)

        for _, colour := range arrayOfColours {
            relevantRelation[baseColour] = append(relevantRelation[baseColour], colour.subColour)
        }
    }

    // Add indirectly related colours
    for baseColour, arrayOfColours := range relevantRelation {
        for _, colour := range arrayOfColours {
            // Get an array of all colours which is not linked to baseColour
            for _, subColour := range relevantRelation[colour] {
                if !checkMembership(relevantRelation[baseColour], subColour) {
                    relevantRelation[baseColour] = append(relevantRelation[baseColour], subColour)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Add no. of colours which can eventually contain a "shiny gold" bag
    for _, arrayOfColours := range relevantRelation {
        if checkMembership(arrayOfColours, "shiny gold") {
            count++
        }
    }
    return
}

func main() {
    // Read input
    file, _ := os.Open("input.txt")
    defer file.Close()

    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(file)
    var input [][]string

    for scanner.Scan() {
        rule := strings.Split(scanner.Text(), " ")
        input = append(input, rule)
    }

    relation := relationBetweenColours(input)
    fmt.Println(part1(relation))
}
```

When I tried my code against the small sample input given in the question, it produces the correct result.
However, upon running it against the [full input](https://pastebin.com/XTp2tj45) given to me, it produces seemingly different and wrong result each time. The output is anywhere between 10 to 50 and changes each time (The correct answer for my input for Part 1 is `213`).

My question is:

1. What exactly is going on here which causes different result each time?
2. What can I do to overcome this problem and solve the question?

Answer (score 2):

Golang maps are not ordered. So the way you store then and retrive values will have the impact on how the order would be read. One possible thing you can do is sort the map keys as you'd wish and then use it. Or you can create a slice with indexes/keys to map. This will have the order you set.

```
func getOrderedKeys(myMap map[string][]Colours) []string {
    keys := make([]string, 0)
    for k, _ := range collection {
        keys = append(keys, k)
    }
    sort.Strings(keys)
    return keys
}
```

Now, every time you use this map, get sorted keys and then use the keys in order to get the map value.

If you do not want to have sorted keys, what other thing you can do is create a slice and use that as ordered keys.

```
func relationBetweenColours(input [][]string) (relation map[string][]Colours, keys []string) {
    relation = make(map[string][]Colours)

    for _, rule := range input {
        baseColour := strings.Join(rule[:2], " ")
        relation[baseColour] = make([]Colours, 0)
        keys = append(keys, baseColour)
        
        ...
    }
    return
}
```

Then use the keys generated as such to iterate over map.

Bottom line is **golang maps are not ordered**.